# Is there a cap on how powerful you can make "fortify enchanting"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What disenchantable item has fortify enchanting?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40939/what-disenchantable-item-has-fortify-enchanting)

I was wondering if you made an enchantment: "fortify enchanting" with 100 enchanting, all enchanting perks, with a grand soul gem. than you could equip the item and repeat first step for unlimited enchanting power. I need to know if there is a cap on this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put Fortify: Enchanting on gear for precisely this reason.

Alchemy and Enchanting have a bit of a feedback loop, but diminishing returns means you cap out at a 29% bonus, and no further.

Answer (score 0):

**Technically Yes, Mechnically not really.**

It's possible through some clever use of Alchemy, Restoration and Enchanting to raise your Enchanting level through the roof. For details of the method see this link: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Skyrim:Alchemy/Enchanting_Loop

I would imagine that there is a theoretical cap due to the fact that computers can only store numbers of a certain size natively. However in practise I doubt this would affect this loop unless you looped it a very **very** large number of times.