# Catalogue of Armor Enchantments: gauntlets that can fortify the ability to enchant items

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I searched for information about the item that the Catalogue of Armor Enchantments talks about: "*There are even examples of gauntlets that are enchanted to improve the wearers ability to enchant things.*"

I found [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40939/what-disenchantable-item-has-fortify-enchanting?rq=1). But in the answers I didn't find anything related to what the catalogue states.

Is it a lie? Or does this item exist?

Answer (score 4):

There are no wearable items with the Fortify Enchanting property in Skyrim. None.

No gloves, no rings, no weapons, no clothes, none at all. You cannot equip an item to increase your enchanting skill. The only way to boost enchanting is with a potion or, or through the use of a mod or console cheats. The in game book, as with many in game books, is inaccurate.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of such inaccuracy?

Comment: I have no way to prove a negative.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Dragonborn DLC, you can obtain the relics of Ahzidal from Kolbjorn Barrow on Solstheim. There is a dragon priest mask, ancient nord style helmet, armor, gauntlets, boots and 2 rings. All have unique enchantments. Ahzidal's Boots of Waterwalking have an additional property. When you wear the boots along with 3 other relics of Ahzidal(any 3 more for a total of 4. 5 negates the effect) you will then have Ahzidal's Genius active on your character while you wear them. This adds 10 to your enchanting skill. You can see this by looking at the bottom right of your screen while in the arcane enchanter interface(probably shows up under your enchanting skill in the skill screen as well. Haven't tested that).